# Facebook-IOS-SDK pod installation issue

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Xcode 10.2 and swift 5. When I update my pods, facebook SDK pod giving me errors. please see attached image

[image]

is anyone facing this issue? How can I install pods with facebook-IOS-SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This library is deprecated, seems like you need to replace the old pod with the 'FBSDKCoreKit', 'FBSDKLoginKit', and 'FBSDKShareKit' pods

[Source](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FacebookSDK)

[The old library's source](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK)